# Super constructor with null reference

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to create a subclass in AS3, with 2 parameters in the constructor, but, when I call the constructor of the subclass, I get this message: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Main Class:

```
public class Machine extends Observable implements Observer {

        public var name: String;
        public var ip: String;
        public var tires: Array;

        private var updateTimer: Timer;
        private var req: Request;

        public function Machine(name: String, ip: String): void {
            this.name = name;
            this.ip = ip;
            this.tires = new Array();
            updateTimer = new Timer(2000, 1);
            updateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timedUpdate);
            updateTimer.start();
            req = new Request();
            timedUpdate(null);
        }
    }
```

Subclass:

```
public class MachineOLD extends Machine {

        private var _req: Request;

        public function MachineOLD(name: String, ip: String): void {
            super(name, ip);
            _req = new Request();
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
var m: MachineOLD;
m = new MachineOLD("new old machine", "192.168.0.159");
```

I'm using Adobe Animate version 19.1 (build 349) to build and run the code.

Comment: Turn debugging on (File > Publish Settings > Permit Debugging) and learn the exact line that produces the said error to narrow the problem.

Comment: The line that produces the error is : super(name, ip);

Comment: There are no "access property" instructions in that line. You access properties/methods via dot notation (e.g. **this.x**) or square bracket notation (e.g. **this["x"]**).

Comment: could you show the code of Observable

Comment: I have found the problem. The object _req is used by timedUpdate(null) in the Super Class, than it is a null object when calling super(). The solution are create this object before call super().